# FB Like button / if statement / innerHTML

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to make it so that when you: 
press the Facebook like button,
the innerHTML of #pChange will change to whatever it may be.

I'm guessing there's another way to set the if statement.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var myTest = document.getElementById('likeButton');

if(myTest === true) {
    document.getElementById('pChange').innerHTML="This is a test";
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TobaccoJoe/P7B4t/

Comment: afaik the facebook javascript sdk has support for a callback function for exactly these cases.

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle the click event on the button, so a plain "if statement" won't be enough.
Unfortunately, iframes don't allow you to set an "onclick" property. The best solution would be to see if Facebook allows you to set a callback on the iframe.

Another way that would work I think would be something like :

```
var myTest = document.getElementById('likeButton');
var thisDocument=document;
var clickHandler = function(event){
     thisDocument.getElementById('pChange').innerHTML="This is a test";
};
myTest.contentDocument.addEventListener("click",clickHandler,false);
```